# ROS Answers SE migration: tab completion

Tags: ros, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 running Hydro and with roscd I can't tab complete. Is there something wrong with my install or is that just not a feature available with the ROS file navigation tools.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194720/tab-completion/) by [candidcypher](https://answers.ros.org/users/20435/candidcypher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roscd should tab-complete ROS package names.

If this isn't working, you should check:

- That you're sourcing the `setup.bash` and not `setup.sh` in your workspace. (setup.sh is for posix-compliant shells that don't have any fancy features.)
- That your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH are set properly (The setup files should do this automatically when you source them, but there's always a possibility that something is overwriting them later)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [candidcypher](https://answers.ros.org/users/20435/candidcypher/) on 2014-10-10**:
Yeah, my source is correct: $source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash Not sure what is preventing it... Just strange. Thanks for the quick feedback!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-10**:
Are you using a shell other than bash?

**Comment by [wouter_tnl](https://answers.ros.org/users/20414/wouter_tnl/) on 2014-10-20**:
Note that ahendrix was referring to the setup.bash in your catkin workspace (i.e. "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash"), which is another script than the one you mention (in /opt/ros/). You need to run BOTH scripts (first /opt/ros/... then the one in your catkin workspace) to get it to work.

**Comment by [candidcypher](https://answers.ros.org/users/20435/candidcypher/) on 2014-10-20**:
Thanks guys! That makes a lot of sense.